# Commits in the absence of locks in CockroachDB

Tags: cockroachdb

I'm trying to understand how ACID in *CockroachDB* works without locks, from an application programmer's point of view.  Would like to use it for an accounting / ERP application.

When two users update the same database field (e.g. a general ledger account total field) at the same time what does *CockroachDB* do?  Assuming each is updating many other non-overlapping fields at the same time as part of the respective transactions.

Will the aborted application's commit process be informed about this immediately at the time of the commit?

Do we need to take care of additional possibilities than, for example, in ACID/locking *PostgreSQL* when we write the database access code in our application?

Or is writing code for accessing *CockroachDB* for all practical purposes the same as for accessing a standard *RDBMS* with respect to commits and in general.

Of course, ignoring performance issues / joins, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to understand how ACID in CockroachDB works without locks, from an application programmer's point of view. Would like to use it for an accounting / ERP application.

CockroachDB does have locks, but uses different terminology. Some of the existing documentation that talks about optimistic concurrency control is currently being updated.

> When two users update the same database field (e.g. a general ledger account total field) at the same time what does CockroachDB do? Assuming each is updating many other non-overlapping fields at the same time as part of the respective transactions.

One of the transactions will block waiting for the other to commit. If a deadlock between the transactions is detected, one of the two transactions involved in the deadlock will be aborted.

> Will the aborted application's commit process be informed about this immediately at the time of the commit?

Yes.

> Do we need to take care of additional possibilities than, for example, in ACID/locking PostgreSQL when we write the database access code in our application?
>
> Or is writing code for accessing CockroachDB for all practical purposes the same as for accessing a standard RDBMS with respect to commits and in general.

At a high-level there is nothing additional for you to do. CockroachDB defaults to serializable isolation which can result in more transaction restarts that weaker isolation levels, but comes with the advantage that the application programmer doesn't have to worry about anomalies.